How to add Windows PowerShell (v5) to VS Code Terminal?
I have no option to start a Windows PowerShell (i.e v5) terminal in VSCode

However in my settings I see it and I can set it as the default profile:

Nevertheless, starting a new terminal always starts pwsh.exe (PS v7) and I cannot start powershell.exe. How to start a powershell.exe session?

In the VSCode status bar at the bottom right you can see "PowerShell" which is the current language. On the left of that there is a {} symbol which lets you switch the PowerShell session between PowerShell (7.x) and Windows PowerShell (5.x).

@zett42 That applys to the powershell extension and not the vs code terminal. I want to start a new terminal in Windows PowerShell (not PowerShell Core).


The screenshots you're showing relate to using PowerShell as a general-purpose shell in Visual Studio Code.

The default (shell) profile is used:

When you click directly on the + icon in the integrated terminal's toolbar
When you first open the integrated terminal pane, unless preempted by a special-purpose shell: see next point.




By contrast, if you have the PowerShell extension installed, a special-purpose shell called the PowerShell-Integrated Console (PIC) is used whenever you open a PowerShell source-code file (e.g., *.ps1) for editing.

This extension uses its own, separate settings to determine which PowerShell edition / installed copy to use by default, and it defaults to PowerShell (Core) 7 if found installed in a well-known location.

As zett42 notes, with the PIC active in the integrated terminal, you can click on the {} icon in the status bar - which shows you which PowerShell edition the PIC currently uses - and click on Show PowerShell Session Menu, which opens a menu allowing you to select a different PowerShell edition to use, and also allows you to configure additional PowerShell locations to use, if necessary.

You should see two Switch To: menu items relating to Windows PowerShell, Windows PowerShell (x64) and Windows PowerShell (x86); choose the former for a regular, 64-bit session; the latter for a 32-bit one.

An alternative method to reach the session menu is: Open the Command Palette (select menu command View > Command Palette... or press Ctrl+Shift+P) and navigate to PowerShell: Show Session Menu; searching for powershell session should be enough to locate it.







Indeed I am concerned with the shell (not necessarily the default) and not the extension. I just want to be able to start Windows PowerShell (v5) and PowerShell (7v) as terminals and I am not able to select it. Even if I set Windows PowerShell in terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows it still starts pwsh and not powershell by default.

In fact if I set any default shell except WPS it works fine. It's like something is hijacking WPS within VSCode and redirecting it to PS7.

@Marc: That's mysterious; I can neither reproduce your symptom nor do I have an explanation. What happens if you make cmd.exe your default shell and manually launch powershell.exe from there? You could also try to set up a custom profile that invokes powershell.exe, possibly via cmd /c.
